# How to fetch a value from a map?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

How to fetch 'theme' from the below $themes map?

```
$themes: (
  default: (
    theme: blue,
  )
);
```

I tried with the below map with single child and it works with `map-get()`

> SCSS

```
$default: (
  theme: red,
);

@function fetchColor($issuer, $key) {
  @return map-get($issuer, $key);
}

.navbar-brand {
  background : fetchColor($default, theme);
}
```

> Result

```
.navbar-brand {
  background: red;
}
```

How to fetch the same from '$themes' map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a solution as [described by css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/#deep-get):

```
$themes: (
  default: (
    theme: blue,
  )
);

@function fetchColor($map, $keys...) {
    @each $key in $keys {
        $map: map-get($map, $key);
    }
    @return $map;
}

.navbar-brand {
  background:  fetchColor($themes, default, theme);
}
```